# Regarding git svn with Eclipse projects

Tags: eclipse, git, svn, version-control, git-svn

Here's the configuration of my svn repo:

```
branches
  jack
    proj1
    proj2
  hobbes
    proj1
    proj2
trunk
  proj1
```

Both `proj1` and `proj2` are Eclipse projects. 
I've done a `git svn -s clone` successfully.
There's a problem, though. `git-svn` considers `trunk` to be my main directory (when in the `trunk` git branch, that is), meaning that having my `.gitignore` inside `proj1` won't work. But I need to have `.gitignore` inside `proj1`, otherwise when someone checks out from `proj1` (through `svn`), `.gitignore` won't be included!

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your layout is not standard (the `-s` switch). You'll have to specify all `--trunk=<trunk_subdir>`, `--tags=<tags_subdir>` and `--branches=<branches_subdir>`. You should not have `trunk` as a directory next to your `.git` directory. Stdlayout would be:

```
proj1
  trunk
  branches
    jack
    hobbes
  tags
proj2
  trunk
  branches
    jack
    hobbes
  tags
```

I don't know if with your svn layout it is at all possible to correctly describe one project and it's branches and tags to `git svn`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I wasn't even aware that I wasn't following a standard svn layout.